# Playframework 2 SQLite

Tags: sqlite, playframework-2.0

I am trying to get SQLite working with the playframework but so far no luck.

I have Downloaded sqlitejdbc-v056.jar and put it into the lib folder.

I then changed the application.conf:

```
db.driver=org.sqlite.JDBC
db.url="jdbc:sqlite:/db/geolookup.sqlite"
db.default.user=sa
db.default.password=sa
```

I created a folder db and drop my sqlite db into it.

Now I start play with play run

Everything seems to compile ok, but when I call the url: http://127.0.0.1:9000

I get the following error:

driver.url has type STRING rather than OBJECT
with the following line highlited:

```
db.driver=org.sqlite.JDBC
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try with `db.driver="org.sqlite.JDBC"` ?

Comment: As a side note, you shouldn't directly copy a jar in the lib folder but add the library as a dependency.

To do so, edit `Application.build` and add the following entry to the `appDependencies` list : 

`"org.xerial" % "sqlite-jdbc" % "3.7.2"`

(replace the version with the one you want to use)

You can do this for every dependency you need, the first string is the groupId, the second one the artifactId and the last one the version.

On the next server restart, Play! will resolve and download the dependency for you.

Answer (score 10):

try this:

```
db.default.driver="org.sqlite.JDBC"
db.default.url="jdbc:sqlite:/home/tex/dbtest"
db.default.user="sa"
db.default.password=""
```

Notice that the folder of the db must be an absolute path !

(BTW: with this configuration the application starts but when I try to run the evolution it throws an exception, I think this is a "dialect" problem...)

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks, that helped, actually I did not have the default in the driver and url part.  About the evolution thing, I read that there is a dialect jar for sqlite you can download and then it is supposed to work ...

Comment: hi there, I'm having this dialect problem, do you know where is this jar that fix it?

Comment: It does *not* have to be an absolute path. If you just remove the leading `/` it'll work, e.g., `jdbc:sqlite:relative/path/test.db`

Answer (score 1):

You are propably using the wrong method to get the data from the config. From your error I assume you use it like this:

```
configuration.getConfig("db.driver")
```

But this method expects an JSON object under the path "db.driver". Since under the "db.driver" path you have a string, you should read the data using this method:

```
configuration.getString("db.driver")
```

This will make the "rather than OBJECT" error go away.